# Using python (on mac) to scrape list of companies on Linkedin - defaults to retrying or <999> error

Tags: python, html, error-handling, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm a novice, and am trying to automatically pull just the details from each company page on Linkedin.

I'm tinkering a piece of code I found, which does not progress beyond the requests.get and my output immediately defaults to retrying. This happens when I enable the headers as a parameter. When I leave it out, I actually get a <999> response.

Any ideas on how to progress here? How do I move resolve the 999 error, or how do I understand what is wrong if the program immediately defaults to retrying with the headers added.

```
from lxml import html
import csv, os, json 
import requests
from time import sleep
import certifi
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()



def linkedin_companies_parser(url):
for i in range(5):
    try:

        print("looking at the headers")
        headers = {
        "accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
        "accept-language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6",
        "user-agent" : " Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}

        print ("Fetching :",url)   
        response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, verify=False)
        print (response)
        formatted_response = response.content.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
        print (formatted_response)
        doc = html.fromstring(formatted_response)
        print ("we have come here")

        datafrom_xpath = doc.xpath('//code[@id="stream-promo-top-bar-embed-id-content"]//text()')
        content_about = doc.xpath('//code[@id="stream-about-section-embed-id-content"]')
        if not content_about:
            content_about = doc.xpath('//code[@id="stream-footer-embed-id-content"]')
        if content_about:
            pass
            # json_text = content_about[0].html_content().replace('<code id="stream-footer-embed-id-content"><!--','').replace('<code id="stream-about-section-embed-id-content"><!--','').replace('--></code>','')

        if datafrom_xpath:
            try:
                json_formatted_data = json.loads(datafrom_xpath[0])

                company_name = json_formatted_data['companyName'] if 'companyName' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                size = json_formatted_data['size'] if 'size' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                industry = json_formatted_data['industry'] if 'industry' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                description = json_formatted_data['description'] if 'description' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                follower_count = json_formatted_data['followerCount'] if 'followerCount' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                year_founded = json_formatted_data['yearFounded'] if 'yearFounded' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                website = json_formatted_data['website'] if 'website' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                type = json_formatted_data['companyType'] if 'companyType' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None
                specialities = json_formatted_data['specialties'] if 'specialties' in json_formatted_data.keys() else None

                if "headquarters" in json_formatted_data.keys():
                    city = json_formatted_data["headquarters"]['city'] if 'city' in json_formatted_data["headquarters"].keys() else None
                    country = json_formatted_data["headquarters"]['country'] if 'country' in json_formatted_data['headquarters'].keys() else None
                    state = json_formatted_data["headquarters"]['state'] if 'state' in json_formatted_data['headquarters'].keys() else None
                    street1 = json_formatted_data["headquarters"]['street1'] if 'street1' in json_formatted_data['headquarters'].keys() else None
                    street2 = json_formatted_data["headquarters"]['street2'] if 'street2' in json_formatted_data['headquarters'].keys() else None
                    zip = json_formatted_data["headquarters"]['zip'] if 'zip' in json_formatted_data['headquarters'].keys() else None
                    street = street1 + ', ' + street2
                else:
                    city = None
                    country = None
                    state = None
                    street1 = None
                    street2 = None
                    street = None
                    zip = None

                data = {
                            'company_name': company_name,
                            'size': size,
                            'industry': industry,
                            'description': description,
                            'follower_count': follower_count,
                            'founded': year_founded,
                            'website': website,
                            'type': type,
                            'specialities': specialities,
                            'city': city,
                            'country': country,
                            'state': state,
                            'street': street,
                            'zip': zip,
                            'url': url
                        }
                return data
            except:
                print ("cant parse page"), url

        # Retry in case of captcha or login page redirection
        if len(response.content) < 2000 or "trk=login_reg_redirect" in url:
            if response.status_code == 404:
                print ("linkedin page not found")
            else:
                raise ValueError('redirecting to login page or captcha found')
    except :
        print ("retrying :"),url

def readurls():
companyurls = ['https://www.linkedin.com/company/tata-consultancy-services']
extracted_data = []
for url in companyurls:
    extracted_data.append(linkedin_companies_parser(url))
    f = open('data.json', 'w')
    json.dump(extracted_data, f, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
readurls()
```

Answer (score 1):

The status code `999` sent from Linkedin typically indicates Access denial either due to bot activity or some other security reason.

Its best to simulate an actual user by using Chrome or Firefox in headless mode and crawling the pages. It will eliminate the need to set cookies manually or passing headers, which saves a lot of time.

You can use **Selenium** with python to automate the browser navigation and scraping.

PS: Make sure you're not running your program from an AWS or other popular hosting ips as these ip ranges are blocked by Linkedin for non-authenticated sessions.